# Response a json from a server in Dart

Tags: json, http, server, dart

I'm trying to make a web app, so it should be possible to create an user. Therefor I'm trying to get all user emails from the database and to respond the back to the client.

So I'm having a request on my server, and how can I send the json back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just return it with write worked for me.